# typescript Record accepts array, why?

Tags: arrays, typescript, record

Can anyone explain why this compiles in typescript?
I tried some googling and looking it up in the typescript documentation but didn't find the answer.

```
type RecType = Record<string, any>
const arr: RecType = [1, 2, "three"] //or new Array(1, 2, 3)

console.log(arr)  // [1, 2, "three"] 
console.log(Array.isArray(arr)) // true
console.log(Object.keys(arr)) // ["0", "1", "2"]
```

here's a [typescript playground link with the code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGAVc0C8sEHsBOATAPAM7DYCWAdgOYA0UAhuSAHwCwAUPJucfdtgFwYkKKOgDaARloAmWgCJgAC2wQIcgLpQA9FpxRyEAO5QAgnzogAFFKiyoAZgCU7dp26YANhAB0HzJUs6PkcobS0oSRl5JRU1TVcuQk8fPwCzbAtvUkJ0i0DgkJ0oEgBXCAT3L19-SwB5ACMAKwRgbwBrCBBCfOxHQvCxOQAGOXkJUag5aQ0odiA)

Comment: Why do you believe this should not be accepted?

Comment: I understand why it can be accepted, because array can be treated as a "record" or "map" by turning its indices into keys.
I'm just not sure what mechanism in typescript compiler allows this and couldn't find any previous answer (or docu) to this, is it too obvious and i'm missimg something?

Answer (score 3):

After resting a little, coming back to the problem and looking a little deeper I think I understand it.

this is how Record is defined in typescript (from it's source code)

```
type Record<K extends keyof any, T> = {
    [P in K]: T;
};
```

an array can be assigned to this because

- `keyof` operator will return the array's indices as the keys (similar to how Object.keys does).
- the accessor `[P in K]: T` is valid for array because `array["0"]` is a valid way to access index 0 of the array (and so is `array[0]`

I hope I got it right, feel free to make corrections.

Answer (score 3):

If you want an actual string keyed object with unknown values, but disallow arrays, it's better to use `Record<string, unknown>` to exclude arrays from being passed in. See [TS Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBDATgcwFyIBKAphHFgCYA8AzlFjGDgDSIZgCeAfAJSIDeAWABQiMYizEoILEmw4A3CIC%20IkSnT8MBAOQ7WAIwIBGVhAL9lrCgXohiynkuEa0AbS279iI4lOJzAStEG0Q7BwBdJzUXcGh4JANsTFwCEjJKWnpGFkRwAGswOAB3MF4BEXEJKRk5XGdVYREkrDRPRD1DEzMLYNDwx2cW93bOn26A3utbLHtlKIUgA).

Answer (score 2):

You might be surprised, that it accepts more than just the array and object. All of the following are valid assignments:

```
const a: Record<string, any> = []; 
const b: Record<string, any> = {}; 
const c: Record<string, any> = () => {};
const d: Record<string, any> = new Map();
const e: Record<string, any> = new Date();
const f: Record<string, any> = new Boolean(); 
const g: Record<string, any> = new String();
const h: Record<string, any> = class Klass{};
```

When you call a constructor with `new`, then the `instanceof Object` will return true:

```
function instanceOfObject(arg: Record<string, any>) {
    return arg instanceof Object;
}

// all true
console.log(
    instanceOfObject([]),
    instanceOfObject({}),
    instanceOfObject(() => {}),
    instanceOfObject(new Map()),
    instanceOfObject(new Date()),
    instanceOfObject(new Boolean()),
    instanceOfObject(new String()),
    instanceOfObject(class Klass{}),
)
```

So, the `Record` here is only a nickname for `{ [P in string]: any; }` which means something like "having a **string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures)**". Effectively our `instanceOfObject` function accepts any objects/instances.

Remember that TypeScript is structurally typed, so it checks the objects interface and looks for the signature. [Here the `Object` interface has the string signature.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/1a8406d8b05e8efea768a1788cc9024f9425a1e5/src/lib/core.d.ts#L77)

Perhaps a better name for the `Record` would be `Indexed`, so as to not confuse it with a dictionary which is common in other languages, but not available in JavaScript.

For example, we know that array can be indexed by a numeric index.
So we can assign:

```
const arr: Record<number, unknown> = [1,2,3]; // OK
```

But you might be again surprised:

```
const arr: Record<number, unknown> = "whoa"; // OK
```

Yes, even a string literal "can be assigned to Record". This works because [string is indexable by number.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/1a8406d8b05e8efea768a1788cc9024f9425a1e5/src/lib/core.d.ts#L416) Also note, that literal types are *autoboxed* in JavaScript, and not initialized with `new`, so the `instanceof` fails.

```
console.log("str" instanceof String); // false
console.log(new String("str") instanceof String); // true
```

That's why you cannot pass the `"whoa"` literal to the previous function:

```
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type  
// 'Record<string, any>'
instanceOfObject("whoa"); // ERR
```

That's why we use the `typeof` operator like in `typeof "str" === "string"` for literal values, and also we avoid using the `String()` constructor and related classes.

So when you want to accept only object literals, use the `Record<string, unknown>` which does not permit the object instances from above, and not even the array, as it does not have the string index signature:

```
// Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, unknown>'.
//  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'number[]'
const obj: Record<string, unknown> = [1];
```

[Checkout TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=5.3.2#code/PTAEEsDsGcBcENIGMCm1RPgGyygJqAO7iwAWokKhAsAFAgQwLIoD2AZhoqAEYqgBXaPjpJWTUPABcoAEooxAJzwAeOIqgBzADSTIATwB8oALygA2gF0A3KFHi4vGfKWr1W3YiOnQAbwC%20tvYSSM4KrMpqsBqQOnreZgAUAJSmxgHWwY54Ya5RMXFexmaUhKAAsvAADimZtGISKLkRbtEe8cUUVKAAIvCwKLVZsKDszZHusZ4GnaWgAEKsrLiItXb1DiOa460F0wldZQDKbbFDGxKkO-ntRT5IWPDQ6ADSj88ZdHTsAsiw4OJGHBEKgAPLsUE8ABWClgiXgim2cnCE1OhRmqV8dFAONAihQsAEikgkkRQOYqA4oEhMKQsDq-i%209DA2CwoGiAhQWWWKAAdFhWJpEtjcVBgSxwTTYYkrMltCKcWKKShJdDpQE5QrySCVRC1XTEik0n5-JraLjtRK9bS4XNKjVkmaLUqdaqbYk5n0BiknaKmK7rdK5oseatHfLzX7xWDAwa5icCj6I87-VapQaHk9Xu9oBqI8k6kyGo4EYprpABABbPiKXS-ADWkFYhEgnXMAEZtAAmbQAZhsRc2oHU5arNbrkEbzdbPgARIRSKx4LPC7QXWn9XD54vlwXQAwAKKyWSDiSsaHXSZxBtNltt9sD2hAA)